# Is there a way to force two sets of figures to be placed in one page?

Tags: latex

Here is my Latex code.

```
\begin{figure}[hp]
    \makebox[\textwidth]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ACEM_graph3_size1.png}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ACEM_graph4_size1.png}
    }
    \caption{Cohort with captial $< 1000$}
    \label{ACEM1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[hp]
    \makebox[\textwidth]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ACEM_graph3_size2.png}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ACEM_graph4_size2.png}
    }
    \caption{Cohort with captial $> 1000$}
    \label{ACEM2}
\end{figure}
```

The two figures are connected side by side, and there are two sets. Therefore there are in total four figures. I want the four figures placed in one page, with each captions available for each set. (example below picture). Thank you!!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the two sets are not separated, place them into a single figure environment. You can use the `\captionof` macro from the caption package to add additional captions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hp]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
    \caption{Cohort with captial $< 1000$}
    \label{ACEM1}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
    \captionof{figure}{Cohort with captial $> 1000$}
    \label{ACEM2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer worked! Thank you.
One caveat is that it did not work with using \makebox[\textwidth]{ } inside. So I deleted \makebox[\textwidth]{ }

Comment: @acubens555 The `\makebox{}` is completely unnecessary if you comment out the line ending as shown in my answer. With these additional spaces removed, your images fit in one line.